# How to deal with a 200 mysql concurrent connections?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am building an app with php on godaddy there will be at least 200 computers conected at the same time, my boos asked me what woud happen if more than 200 got on simultaneuly.
I checked at godaddy and the limit is 200 concurrent conections per user.
I dont understan what this means, what happens if more request are done? how can i prepare for this?

I am using codeigniter for the app

Thanks for the tips guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what type of concurrent connections are we talking about here.
Let's presume we're talking about HTTP connections to your website.

Number "200" of concurrent connections means that actually if you have 200 users which do something at the same time on your website, then the next (201th) user will get the "Too many connections error" and will be refused to view the website.

It also means, though (because even active users don't do navigation at the same exact moments and they usually do not take more than a second of virtual server time) your concurrent user peak is around 10 times that number (somewhere between 2000 and 3000 users).

You can chech the GoDaddy FAQ here - https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3206/how-many-visitors-can-view-my-site-at-once.

If you boss is worrying that he will have more than 3000 active users on the website he should either try upgrading the GoDaddy plan or look for a dedicated server and a good web admin (http://www.hetzner.de/ provides the former).